# How to get a curve on top edge of the selected bottom navigation?

Tags: android, canvas, path, bezier, curve

I just started working on a project and thought of putting a curvy bottomnavigationview more like a wave where the user clicks the bump generates.
Like this

[image]

I pretty much found a library where the dev has done a fantastic job by adding a topedgetreatment to items. However, I'm more interested in making this with a bezier curve. I went through a lot of codes but didn't work.

Can somebody please help me get a hint as to how a bump should be drawn animatically.

Below is what I tried to do but that is not what I want to achieve.

```
public class CurvedBottomNavigationView extends BottomNavigationView {
 private Path mPath;
 private Paint mPaint;
/** the CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS represent the radius of the fab button */
 public final int CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS = 256 / 3;
 // the coordinates of the first curve
 public Point mFirstCurveStartPoint = new Point();
 public Point mFirstCurveEndPoint = new Point();
 public Point mFirstCurveControlPoint2 = new Point();
 public Point mFirstCurveControlPoint1 = new Point();
//the coordinates of the second curve
 @SuppressWarnings(“FieldCanBeLocal”)
 public Point mSecondCurveStartPoint = new Point();
 public Point mSecondCurveEndPoint = new Point();
 public Point mSecondCurveControlPoint1 = new Point();
 public Point mSecondCurveControlPoint2 = new Point();
 public int mNavigationBarWidth;
 public int mNavigationBarHeight;
public CurvedBottomNavigationView(Context context) {
 super(context);
 init();
 }
public CurvedBottomNavigationView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
 super(context, attrs);
 init();
 }
public CurvedBottomNavigationView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
 super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
 init();
 }
private void init() {
 mPath = new Path();
 mPaint = new Paint();
 mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
 mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
 setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
 }
@Override
 protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
 super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
}
@Override
 protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
 super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
 // get width and height of navigation bar
 // Navigation bar bounds (width & height)
 mNavigationBarWidth = getWidth();
 mNavigationBarHeight = getHeight();
 // the coordinates (x,y) of the start point before curve
 mFirstCurveStartPoint.set((mNavigationBarWidth / 2) — (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) — (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 3), 0);
 // the coordinates (x,y) of the end point after curve
 mFirstCurveEndPoint.set(mNavigationBarWidth / 2, CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4));
 // same thing for the second curve
 mSecondCurveStartPoint = mFirstCurveEndPoint;
 mSecondCurveEndPoint.set((mNavigationBarWidth / 2) + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 3), 0);
// the coordinates (x,y) of the 1st control point on a cubic curve
 mFirstCurveControlPoint1.set(mFirstCurveStartPoint.x + CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4), mFirstCurveStartPoint.y);
 // the coordinates (x,y) of the 2nd control point on a cubic curve
 mFirstCurveControlPoint2.set(mFirstCurveEndPoint.x — (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) + CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS, mFirstCurveEndPoint.y);
mSecondCurveControlPoint1.set(mSecondCurveStartPoint.x + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) — CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS, mSecondCurveStartPoint.y);
 mSecondCurveControlPoint2.set(mSecondCurveEndPoint.x — (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4)), mSecondCurveEndPoint.y);
 }
@Override
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
 super.onDraw(canvas);
 mPath.reset();
 mPath.moveTo(0, 0);
 mPath.lineTo(mFirstCurveStartPoint.x, mFirstCurveStartPoint.y);
mPath.cubicTo(mFirstCurveControlPoint1.x, mFirstCurveControlPoint1.y,
 mFirstCurveControlPoint2.x, mFirstCurveControlPoint2.y,
 mFirstCurveEndPoint.x, mFirstCurveEndPoint.y);
mPath.cubicTo(mSecondCurveControlPoint1.x, mSecondCurveControlPoint1.y,
 mSecondCurveControlPoint2.x, mSecondCurveControlPoint2.y,
 mSecondCurveEndPoint.x, mSecondCurveEndPoint.y);
mPath.lineTo(mNavigationBarWidth, 0);
 mPath.lineTo(mNavigationBarWidth, mNavigationBarHeight);
 mPath.lineTo(0, mNavigationBarHeight);
 mPath.close();
canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
 }
}
```

Comment: have you found any solution ?